# JPA does not use sequence

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have created a sequence in the database (PostgreSQL) and I have the following annotations in the domain model.  I am using JPA. However, when I invoke the web service (REST) without an id in the object that I want to create it throws a constraint error. However shouldn't it use a value from the sequence below?

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq", sequenceName = "user_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "user_seq")
private int id;
```

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could
>   not execute statement Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>   ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When value comes from database sequence, [GenerationType.SEQUENCE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#SEQUENCE) should be used as a strategy. `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is used with identity columns.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for spotting that. I have written SEQUENCE in the other classes. Is IDENTITY the correct type to use if you use auto incrementing column values as you can in MySQL for instance? I don't understand the explanation in the API.

Comment: Welcome. Yes, identity is correct choice for MySQL auto increment.